# C - run function before/after main() ended

Tags: c++, c

i have a question for you.
I need find out if i can use some function before or after main() function ended. I can't find some examples for C language. 
Can you give me some advice or examples. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What platform are you writing for?

Comment: Can you not just put the code at the end of `main`? We need more info to provide a truly useful solution. Also, do you need C++ or C, because in C++ you have constructors and destructors available to you.

Comment: Just rename `main()` to eg `oldmain()` and in the new `main()` call `oldmain()` and other functions as needed.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using GCC, you can create [construtors/destructor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) functions:

> The `constructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters `main()`. Similarly, the `destructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically after `main()` completes or `exit()` is called. Functions with these attributes are useful for initializing data that is used implicitly during the execution of the program.

Sample:

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) ctor() { printf("1"); }
void __attribute__ ((destructor))  dtor() { printf("3"); }
int main() { printf("2"); }
```

Output:

```
123
```

Comment: +1. And here is an example: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-that-are-executed-before-and-after-main-in-c/

Answer (score 9):

There is `atexit` function in C (`std::atexit` in C++) which registers a function to be called at program termination.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [atexit()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) for normal program exit, a signal handler (in UNIX) for abnormal exit.

GCC also has the constructor and destructor [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) that do what you want, that's not vanilla C or C++ though.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this problem, some of which have been provided:

- Static CRT intitialization/termination (static object destructor
  "hook")
- Renaming your main and wrapping it with the real main
- Registering a hook with atexit()

It's not clear what you're trying to do, or even whether the question intends "can I do it" or "is it safe to do it"?  Can you clarify?